# How to include pytorch in pyinstaller app?

Tags: python, pytorch, pyinstaller, torch

I am trying to use pyinstaller to "freeze" a python app I've written that uses pytorch. I see that pyinstaller has a hook for torch: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/develop/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-torch.py

But it doesn't appear to work. I still get the following error:

> File "torch/_utils_internal.py", line 53, in get_source_lines_and_file
>   OSError: Can't get source for . TorchScript requires source access in order to carry out
>   compilation, make sure original .py files are available. Original
>   error: could not get source code [28326] Failed to execute script
>   timeslide

I also tried this work-around with no success:

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2666#issuecomment-370789381

I just need a way to get pytorch to install in a pyinstaller app. It doesn't need to be clean or beautiful. Can anyone suggest a solution?

(macOS and python 3.7)